# how to Distinct in JPA Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

how to using distinct in JPA? because I want to get all phone numbers and name in my table, so i get all result by unique , my table name on a database called whatsapp_chat and I want to get by wa_id(my field database)

i tried Lits findDistincByWhatsappid() , Lits findDistincWhatsappid();
I got the error to use them, how to correct way to use Distinct? I am new in Spring boot and Java

i tried this also :

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT wa_id FROM whatsapp_chat")
    List<String> findDistinctWhatsappid();
```

hee is my entity/model :

```
Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "WHATSAPP_CHAT")
@DynamicUpdate
public class WhatsappChat extends Base {
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "WA_ID")
    private String whatsappid;

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    private String messageid;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;

}
```

Comment: Could you add your entity class ?

Comment: As @Arnaud said add the code plus the error messages plus the StackTrace you've got

Comment: i did create entity @Arnaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Write native query:

   ```
   @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT w.WA_ID FROM WHATSAPP_CHAT w", nativeQuery = true)
   List<String> findDistinctWhatsappIds();
   ```
2. Write JPQL query (querying using objects):

   ```
   @Query("SELECT DISTINCT w.whatsappid FROM WhatsappChat AS w")
   List<String> findDistinctWhatsappIds();
   ```

Either way, I would change the method name to be in plural (it is a list) and Uppercase in the Id (column retrieving) to know exactly what it is coming.

NOTE: The method name has no impact in the query itself as it contains the annotation @Query specifying what to execute.

You can test with this ( a little different if not using Spring-boot):

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class WhatsappChatRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    WhatsappChatRepository whatsappChatRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        entityManager.persist(new WhatsappChat("whats1", "whats01", 1));
        entityManager.persist(new WhatsappChat("whats2", "whats02", 2));
        entityManager.persist(new WhatsappChat("whats3", "whats01", 3));
        entityManager.persist(new WhatsappChat("whats4", "whats04", 4));

        entityManager.flush();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTestSameResult() {
        assertEquals(whatsappChatRepository.findDistinctWhatsappIds(), whatsappChatRepository.findDistinctWhatsappIdsNative());

        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("whats01", "whats02", "whats04"), whatsappChatRepository.findDistinctWhatsappIds());
    }
}
```

Comment: so the method name is custum and whatever we like ??

Comment: Yes, the method only matter if you don't have the Query annotation on it.

Comment: how about the in the List ? can i use the domain over string ? because i want to get all data from that domain from database

Comment: You can't @poppop. You would end up having a converter problem, because you are retrieving one column and trying to convert to a whole object type.

Comment: when i put string on it , it show error, and when i use domain in it, it doesnt error and i got the result, but the result now showing the DTO, just string in array

Comment: I added a test case that the methods are returning correct and everything @poppop, maybe you should share the whole entity and stack (spring-boot?). It should work the way I added above.

Comment: the result i got from : List<WhatsappChat> resultPerKey = whatsappChatRepository.findDistinctWhatsappid();
            log.info("ini result per key contacts =====> " + resultPerKey); is Ljava.lang.Object;@2ddc98d3

Comment: Do this to print: resultPerKey.forEach(key-> System.out.println(key.getWhatsappid)); ... What you are printing it is an object because List does not implement the toString() method.

Comment: my previus result was like this [11208390389] that is no wa_id , but i really want to get result to be a model like this : [WhatsappChat(name=Kerry Fisher, whatsappid=16315551234, text=Hello this is an answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is a HQL query, not a native one, hence it uses the class name of the entity along with its fields names.

Consider rewording your query like :

`"SELECT DISTINCT whatsappid FROM WhatsappChat"`

Comment: how about the List<WhatsappChat> methodname ? what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Do as Follows :

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT WA_ID FROM WHATSAPP_CHAT", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findDistinctWhatsappid();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead of the one you are using, you can't use the column directly in the query at jpa until you set nativeQuery field to true. Use this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT W.whatsappid FROM WhatsappChat W")
List<String> findDistinctWhatsappid();
```

Comment: cant we use WhatsappChat Domain in the List ??